# Create api calls in Vite (with ViteSSR / ViteSSG)

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, vuejs3, vite

I'm currently developping a simple eCommerce site with ViteJS.
My Project uses :

- Vue 3
- Vite 2.4
- [vite-plugin-pages](https://github.com/hannoeru/vite-plugin-pages), for automatic route generation (Nuxt Style)
- [vite-ssg](https://github.com/antfu/vite-ssg), for server side generation (SEO optimisation)

Hosting is done on free netlify account (I am open to switch to vercel or other if needed). The Data handling is done via Headless CMS GraphCMS, hosted on their servers.

Following a tutorial on [Stipe integration with NextJS & GraphCMS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2xT3ue-liY) i came across a problem. In NextJs you can natively create server-side api routes, unlike in Vite.
As ViteSSG (Server Side Generated) has the ability of pre-rendering the shipped html, and running code on server-side, I would like to understand how I could create a server route to serve an api without having to go though the hassle of creating and hosting a seperate backend only for a simple call :

> POST https://localhost:3000/api/create-checkout-session

Because if i create the stripe checkout session on the client side (inside payBtn click handler), the data (price, etc ...) could be altered by the client as the handler code would be served client-side. I want this session to be generated on server side and its Id sent back to client to be then used in the checkout process. It would remove the ability to alter the data.

I can share more code if needed, and expand information if something is not clear enough. Thanks for the help !

```js
/* main.js */
import 'vue-global-api'
import { ViteSSG } from 'vite-ssg'
import generatedRoutes from 'virtual:generated-pages'
import { setupLayouts } from 'virtual:generated-layouts'
import App from './App.vue'

const routes = setupLayouts(generatedRoutes)

export const createApp = ViteSSG(
  App,
  { routes },
  (ctx) => {
    // install all modules under `modules/` folder (i18n, nprogress, pwa)
    Object.values(import.meta.globEager('./modules/*.js')).map(i => i.install?.(ctx))
  }
)
```

```js
/* Wanted API route */
import Stripe from 'stripe'
import { useAPI } from '@/utils/GraphCMS'

const graphcms = useAPI()
const stripe = new Stripe(/* STIPE API KEY*/)

export default (req, res) => {
  const { slug } = req.body
  // fetch product from GraphCMS
  const result = await graphcms.getSingleProduct(slug)

  try {
    const session = stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/?id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      cancel_url: `http://localhost:3000/services/${slug}`,
      /*...*/
    })
    res.json(session)
  } catch(e) {
    res.json({ error: {message: e }})
  }

  return
}
```

```html
<!-- Client Side API Call -->
<script setup>
...
/* goPay, called on button click => Should POST data to server-side API route */
const goPay = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // Create checkout session
    const session = await fetch('/api/create-checkout-session', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        slug: service.slug
      })
    })

    // redirect to checkout
  }
</script>

<template>
  <PayBtn @click="goPay" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In NextJs you can natively create server-side api routes

Yes because it has a server component running on Node (so you need a Node server to run the Next/Nuxt site ....unless using "generate" mode)

> As ViteSSG (Server Side Generated) has the ability of pre-rendering the shipped html

Yes, during build time

> and running code on server-side

I don't know why you think this but I really really doubt it. [vite-ssg](https://github.com/antfu/vite-ssg) runs only at build time. It has no server component that is either required or even available at runtime (when serving your pre-rendered pages)

Vite itself is development tool only. Again, the "server" component of Vite is there ONLY to serve resources during development. There are some plugins which allows you to streamline creation of server side routes as [vite-plugin-mix](https://github.com/egoist/vite-plugin-mix) or [fastify-vite](https://fastify-vite.dev/) but both just generates a server-side code bundle for you and you need to setup the Node server to actually run the API

But you really need some server functionality - Stripe documentation is pretty clear in that regard. But you do not need a standalone server (which needs setup and runs 24/7). What you can try is called "serverless computing". Most hosting providers have something like that including Netlify - [Netlify functions](https://www.netlify.com/products/functions/)

I have no direct experience with it but if you [google a bit](https://www.google.com/search?q=vite+netlify+functions) you can find an [examples](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2571) on how to integrate it with Vite (using proxy)